# Is there a way to prevent PyDev from modifying my .project file and creating a .pydevproject file?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have a java project that uses a python script as part of the build process. I also have PyDev installed, but it is for other projects. Whenever I update a file in Eclipse PyDev will create a .pydevproject file and alter my existing .project file. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I cannot find anything that appears related to this behavior in the PyDev preferences page.

Comment: This is causing me particular angst with egit.  In one branch I need the .pydevproject in the other I don't (yet).  When I switch to the branch w/o it, .pydevproject gets created, and then when I try and switch back I get messages about uncommited changes, yet if I try and delete the .pydevproject file, it comes back and I'm stuck not being able to switch branches. "Discard changes" should work, but does not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fixes the original problem, but for the problem in my comment,

1. Right-click on project with .pydevproject
2. Pydev->Remove...